# Automatically convert parameters to a known type

Tags: c#, parameters, types

I have a method that accepts a variable number of string parameters. The problem is that the parameters originate as a variety of different types. This means that i am required to explicitly convert all types to strings (with Convert) as i pass them to the method. Is it possible for the method to do this implicitly, automatically converting parameters, regardless of type, into strings?

Comment: Can't you pass `object[]` in instead of `string[]`?

Comment: Could you give us the method signature and call to clarify thing a bit?

Comment: Why use Convert? Why not simply call ToString()?

Comment: Both 1.ToString() and int i=1;i.ToString() return correct values. Not sure where is problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public string MyFunction(params object[] someobjects)
{
     var asstrings = someobjects.Select(o => (o??"").ToString());
     // for example
     return string.Join(", ", asstrings.ToArray());
}
```

For .NET 4.0 you can drop the `.ToArray()` call as well

Comment: Use this method in combination with overriding the `ToString()` (on the objects) where applicable.

Comment: @slugster The  join  was merely a sample use. The LINQ Select is the crux here

Comment: you misunderstood me - i wasn't commenting on the join, i was simply mentioning that the OP should use your method, and look to override the **default** `ToString()` where applicable to get a suitable representation of the object in string format (otherwise for many objects they are just going to end up with the type name of the object).

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way:

```
string.Format("{0}", param);
```

Comment: I heard that `string.Format` is not the *easiest* way to convert one object to string. At least not for CLR.

Answer (score 0):

You can use object array instead of string array. thats the place where it fits in.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the method, I would recomend passing array of object not strings. And then do the string conversion inside.

```
public void MyMethod(param object[] objs)
{
    String[] strings = objs.Select(o=>o.ToString()).ToArray();

    // work with strings here
}
```

If you can't change the method, you can either do static method, to which you will pass the objects, those objects get converted to strings and then passed to your method.

```
public static void MyMethod(param object[] objs)
{
    String[] strings = objs.Select(o=>o.ToString()).ToArray();

    MyStaticObject.MyMethod(strings);
}
```

Or if it is instance method, then you can make an Extesion method instead.

```
public static void MyMethod(this MyObject t, param object[] objs)
{
    String[] strings = objs.Select(o=>o.ToString()).ToArray();

    t.MyMethod(strings);
}
```